# How to write milp equation for this problem?

Tags: linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Consider the classic network flow problem where the constraint is that the outflow from a vertex is equal to the sum of the inflows to it. Consider having a more specific constraint where the flow can be split between edges.

I have two questions:

1. How can I use a decision variable to identify that node j is receiving items from multiple edges?
2. How to create another equation to determine the cost (2 unit of time per item) of joining x number of items from different edges in the sink node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky modeling question. Let's go by parts.

> Consider having a more specific constraint where the flow can be split between edges

I here assume that you have a classic flow constraint modeled as a real variable set *y_ij*. Therefore, the flow can be split between two or more arcs.

> How can I use a decision variable to identify that node j is receiving items from multiple edges?

You need to create an additional binary variable *z_ij* to represent your flow. You must also create the following constraint:

[image: z_ij >= y_ij]

Next, you will need another additional integer variable set, let's say *p_i* and an additional constraint

[image]

Then, *p_i* will store the number of ingoing arcs in a node *j* which are used to send flow. Since you will try to minimize the cost of joining arcs (I think), you need to use the *<=*.

> How to create another equation to determine the cost(2 unit of time per item) of joining x number of items from different edges in the sink node?

For this, you can use the value of *p_i* and multiply by the predefined cost of joining the flow.

Comment: In my problem each of the arcs will send multiple number of items and I think the value of p_i will give the number of arcs coming to node j. In that case: multiplying the value of p_i and joining cost per item will add the joining cost to node j?

Comment: In this case, you will have a multi-commodity flow (which may be represented by a variable *y_ij^k*, such that each *k* represents an item). Then, you will need to add the index *k* to variable *z* and perform the summation on the last equation on variables *i* and *k*. -- This is a solution, but I'm not 100% sure of that because I don't have a complete description of your problem or your model